# In Russian, when to use an 'interposed' phrasing such as "на чьей ты стороне"?

Tags: грамматика, порядок-слов

> Выбери **на чьей** ты **стороне**.

```
= Choose which side you are on!
```

In expressing the idea of "on which side" in Russian, the phrase "на чьей стороне" is interposed by the pronoun "ты". On the other hand, I'm assuming the addition of a verb such as "стоять" prevents this *separated* construction:

> {vs}: Выбери **на чьей стороне** ты стоишь.

I notice this kind of separated construction often appears with the particle "ли", but I'm wondering if there is a grammatical rule that determines when such a construction is mandatory.

Comment: For _literary_ translation your guess is Ok, but the language does not work like that. The established phase is a bit intimidating, a but colloquial, but very authentic. If I would be asked to translate it to English though, I'd say `Which side are you on?`. Oh, and even `выбери` can be omitted.

Comment: *выбери, на чьей ты стороне стоишь* is perfectly grammatical

Comment: The construction is not mandatory without “стоишь” either. “Ты на чьей стороне?”  or “На чьей стороне ты?” are just fine. I guess the preferred interposed placement of “ты” is simply because of nice iambic meter that results.

Comment: Other constructions ("на чьей ты стороне стоишь", "на чьей стороне ты") while grammatically correct, sound poetic or archaic.

Comment: на чьей ты ЕСТЬ стороне / (on) which side you ARE (on). It seems ot be that "to be" verb is more inclined to be used in such an imposition. Though "на чьей ты стоишь стороне" would work too. The latter variant I would more expect in some song, chanting, poetry, where the rhythm would matter

Comment: @RomanOdaisky re:"because of nice iambic meter that results" hardly any specific meter can be set here. For I can inject few syllables wit hease, and it would not change much (while would certainly disrupt iamb or any other fixed meter). "на чьей стороне ты сегодня стоишь"/"на чьей стороне ты уже стоишь"/"на чьей стороне ты завтра стоишь", etc Also "на чьей стороне ты тут стоишь" or rather "на чьей ты тут стороне стоишь", etc

Comment: Everyone is missing the real reason for different word orders—emphasis. Выбери на чьей ты стороне.— HERE the most important thing is which side, so the word ты is moved to the left. if you wrote—Выбери на чьей стороне ты.—it would mean something like—Choose what side YOU ARE on.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would go with different translation in English for the first Russian sentence, smth. like

> "Choose your side (in the conflict"
>
> "Choose the side you support"

And the second Russian sentence the best translation would be

> "Choose where are you standing"

Basically, the first sentence has a somewhat idiomatic luggage, implying context of conflict, but the second uses verb "стоять" that is mostly used in context of "standing on your legs"

Also, the first sentence should be written as

> Выбери, на чьей ты стороне.

It is a complex sentence. It looks weird, because both parts are grammatically incomplete, but there are two of them, and they should be separated by a comma.

But that's nitpicking. As for the actual question.

In Russian connections between words are not regulated by their position, or, more precisely, position is second to inflections. In this particular case, "чьей" is controlled by "стороне" as both words are of female gender and in Preposition case. *Usual*, i.e. default word order in a sentence is subject-verb-object. The verb in the second part of the first sentence is omitted, so it is subject-object. In part adjective-object, adjective is usually first. So, normally it should be "Выбери, ты на чьей стороне", and it is perfectly fine. However! It is a good idea to specify, what should be chosen, i.e. what links the first part of the sentence and the second. It is "чьей", i.e. what is to be chosen. And so this word is moved forward, and since it does not create ambiguity, it is also perfectly fine. There is not an iron-clad rule for it.